# import { SyncedCron } from 'meteor/percolate:synced-cron';

Tags: meteor, webstorm

Many answers revolve around this question on StackOverflow, but none could solve my problem. I use the WebStorm IDE

On the server side in main.js, I have the following code

```
import { SyncedCron } from 'meteor/percolate:synced-cron';

SyncedCron.add({
  'name': 'Mise a jour GPS',.....
```

**'meteor / percolate: synced-cron'** is underlined and the message is "Module is not installed"

Can someone tell me how to correct this error? This is just a warning I think, but I don't like warnings, I'm always afraid that it hides a real error.

Answer (score 1):

[WEB-42721](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-42721) is fixed in 2019.3.1 that is coming soon